# Autofill textboxes from database based on one textbox value

Tags: c#, database, winforms, textbox

I have a simple form in which there are 3 textboxes as seen in image below :
[image]

using autocompelete function on textchanged event, I am displaying data from database in textbox1(Person Name). Now if your user selects a particular name from suggested items, I want to auto fill textbox2 and textbox3 from database based on value from textbox1.
How should I do that?

Code of textbox1  :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"***my connection string***");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmnd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblTicketDetail";
    SqlDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dReader.Read())
    {
        while (dReader.Read())
            namesCollection.Add(dReader["ContactPerson"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
    }
    dReader.Close();

    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
}
```

now how to autofill textbox2 andd textbox3?

Regards.

Comment: what you want to fill in your second and third textbox

Comment: it is very bad practice to call `Database` Queries in UI Thread. you need to `cache` your data to achieve your goal

Comment: I want to fill textbox2 with number and textbox3 with email based on the selection of texbox1. Number & email are already present in database.
Like if "John" is selected in textbox1, it should pick up number and email of john from database table and display it in textbox2 and textbox3 respectively.

Comment: @Mujahid Daud Khan : Right now, I am not worried about good/bad practices. I just want to achieve functionality.

Comment: if you have same logic for both control (Combobox and Textbox) then specify it in same question for which method is better to use in your way. Don't separate each logic in two different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    try
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(CBCompanies.SelectedValue.ToString());
        DataTable td = new DataTable();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblCustomerCompany where CustomerID =" + CBCompanies.SelectedValue.ToString() + "  ORDER BY CustomerName", conn);
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(td);
        conn.Close();
        textBox3.Text = td.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString();
    }
    catch { }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this effect pretty bad the database performance ?

Answer (score 1):

you can make this work in Form load to populate the list of Contact, then in select change you check if this contact exist and show other detail

```
private Class Contact
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Number{ get; set; }
    public String Mail { get; set; }
}

List<Contact> _listContact = new List<Contact>();
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"***my connection string***");
  con.Open();
  SqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
  cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmnd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblTicketDetail";        
  SqlDataReader dReader;
  dReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

  if (dReader.Read())
   {
     while (dReader.Read())
     {
        namesCollection.Add(dReader["ContactPerson"].ToString());
        Contact cont = Contact{Name = dReader["ContactPerson"].ToString(),
                              Number = dReader["ContactNumber"].ToString()
                              Mail = dReader["ContactMail"].ToString() }
        _listContact.add(cont);
     }
   }
  else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
   }
  dReader.Close();

}
```

then in your textBox1_TextChanged

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if( _listContact.Contain(sender.Text))
   {
      textbox2.Text = _listContact[sender.Text].Number;
      textbox3.Text = _listContact[sender.Text].Mail;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as someone said it is not a good practice to have queries directly in code. But anyways what stops you from adding a where clause in your query. Also I am assuming that you need just the first record in which case, as per my modification, your `namesCollection` object will contain only 1 value. For Example:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"***my connection string***");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    //Changed code here
    cmnd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblTicketDetail where LOWER(name) = LOWER('" + textBox1.Text + "')";
    SqlDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dReader.Read())
    {
        while (dReader.Read())
        {
            namesCollection.Add(dReader["ContactPerson"].ToString());

            //Added code here
            textBox2.Text = dReader["Number"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dReader["email"].ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
    }
    dReader.Close();

    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
}
```

If this not what you want then please elaborate your question.

Hope this helps

Comment: The above code doesn't work. TextBox2 and TextBox3 are not getting updated.

Comment: Did you keep a break point where the textbox's Text property is getting set? Check if the breakpoint is getting hit and that what is the value of reader coming. Also just FYI "TextChanged" event gets fired only when the textbox loses focus. I hope you are pressing tab or clicking elsewhere so that this event gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

1.
You may revise your code and apply LINQ. it is easier  to handle then writing old fashioned query strings.

2.
always close your connection after you ended the DB operation

3.
Cache DB data maybe in the constructor of the main form's creation or in its Loaded event.
Then you may accesss very fast the data from your in-memory object