# code for autocomplete textbox while inserting data in another textbox in c#

Tags: c#

I want to- autocomplete/fill the member name when I insert Member ID
Im dealing with following code on text change event of member ID-

```
try
        {

            //int RowsAffected = 0;
            DataAccess oDataAccess = new DataAccess();
            con.Open();
            oDataAccess.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MemberName FROM AccountInfo where MemberID='" + tbMemberID.Text + "'";
            oDataAccess.cmd.Connection = con;

            tbMemberName.Text = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
//@this line it shows error - object reference not set to an instance of object
            con.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `MemberID` column?

Comment: this is integer type & have primary key on it

Comment: Then why you try to assign your `tbMemberID.Text` as a string?

Comment: scenario is I've stored member info in member table.. now i want to retrieve it on another form of account .. just enter the ID & the name will be shown in name textbox.. that's it

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852192/autofill-textboxes-from-database-based-on-one-textbox-value

Comment: so what should i do..